# How to identify floating point precision at runtime with Rust?

Tags: rust

How to identify that the precision of `1.0005` in the below code ([rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=379c1c7d2437123c64541ce617d64d22&version=stable&mode=debug)) is 4 at runtime?:

```
fn round(n: f64, precision: u32) -> f64 {
    (n * 10_u32.pow(precision) as f64).round() / 10_i32.pow(precision) as f64
}

fn main() {
    let x = 1.0005_f64;

    println!("{:?}", round(x, 1));
    println!("{:?}", round(x, 2));
    println!("{:?}", round(x, 3));
    println!("{:?}", round(x, 4));
    println!("{:?}", round(x, 5));
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know (1) how many digits are necessary to represent the floating point number or (2) how many bits/digits are precise and how many are noise in the floating point number as a result of the computations?

Comment: @MatthieuM. How many digits are necessary to represent the floating point number so that I can use it as input for rounding of addition/subtraction arithmetic.

Comment: This is not a well defined question. How many digits are necessary to represent `0.1`? What about `0.1000`? What about `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`? (I didn't pick that last one randomly, it's the exact value of `0.1f64`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question correctly.  You want the number of decimal places?

```
fn round(n: f64, precision: u32) -> f64 {
    (n * 10_u32.pow(precision) as f64).round() / 10_i32.pow(precision) as f64
}

fn precision(x: f64) -> Option<u32> {
    for digits in 0..std::f64::DIGITS {
        if round(x, digits) == x {
            return Some(digits);
        }
    }
    None
}

fn main() {
    let x = 1.0005_f64;

    println!("{:?}", precision(x));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fcd50136aba13a2f92dca9acbfce251a&version=stable&mode=debug)

I'd also recommend making the types in your round function a bit larger, so you don't run into overflow so fast.  The above code fails already as `x = 1e-10`.

```
fn round(n: f64, precision: u32) -> f64 {
    let precision = precision as f64;
    (n * 10_f64.powf(precision)).round() / 10_f64.powf(precision)
}
```